# Unable to use an Array as environment variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I don't know why I can't use env array variable inside a script ?
In my `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`

```
export HELLO="ee"
export HELLOO=(aaa bbbb ccc)
```

in a shell :

```
> echo $HELLO
ee
> echo $HELLOO
aaa
> echo ${HELLOO[@]}
aaa bbbb ccc
```

in a script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $HELLO
echo $HELLOO
echo ${HELLOO[@]}
---
# Return 
ee
```

Why ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A `bash` array can not be an environment variable as environment variables may only be key-value string pairs.

You may do as the shell does with its `$PATH` variable, which essentially is an array of paths; turn the array into a string, delimited with some particular character not otherwise present in the values of the array:

```
$ arr=( aa bb cc "some string" )
$ arr=$( printf '%s:' "${arr[@]}" )
$ printf '%s\n' "$arr"
aa:bb:cc:some string:
```

Or neater,

```
arr=( aa bb cc "some string" )
arr=$( IFS=:; printf '%s' "${arr[*]}" )
export arr
```

The expansion of `${arr[*]}` will be the elements of the `arr` array separated by the first character of `IFS`, here set to `:`.  Note that if doing it this way, the elements of the string will be *separated* (not *delimited*) by `:`, which means that you would not be able to distinguish an empty element at the end, if there was one.

---

An alternative to passing values to a script using environment variables is (obviously?) to use the command line arguments:

```
arr=( aa bb cc )

./some_script "${arr[@]}"
```

The script would then access the passed arguments either one by one by using the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, `$3` etc, or by the use of `$@`:

```
printf 'First I got "%s"\n' "$1"
printf 'Then  I got "%s"\n' "$2"
printf 'Lastly there was "%s"\n' "$3"

for opt in "$@"; do
    printf 'I have "%s"\n' "$opt"
done
```

Comment: btw, `printf` cycles through its args, `printf 'I have "%s"\n' "$@"`.

Comment: See `fish` or `rc` and derivatives for shells that can export arrays (each with their own encoding understood by themselves only).

Comment: Another aproach is to use `export array_exported="$(printf '%q ' "${array[@]}")"` and re-import (in the same locale) with `typeset -a "array=($array_exported)"` or `eval`, though like in your approach, that  wouldn't preserve the indices of sparse arrays.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I see what you're getting at now. Good. Yes.

Comment: Re: `printf %q`, that should be `((${#array[@]} == 0)) || printf '%q '...`, or it would be wrong for an array with no element. Anyway, using `typeset -p array` would be better and preserve indices. That rings a bell, so there may  be a duplicate of this Q&A here.

Comment: [Bash - Parameter should not be parsed as bash while outputting](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/409728) not really a duplicate.

Comment: Or [Bash - Passing an array to remote hosts via ssh](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/342569)

Comment: This answer is not fully satisfactory. I offer mid-term perspective and a short-term workaround below. `BASH_ENV=<(declare -p HELLO HELLOO) your_script.sh` looks pretty effective to me, though it is not persistent as OP asked.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are bash specific.  Environment variables are name-value pairs.

Read the [specifications on environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), which says, in part:

> The value of an environment variable is a string of characters. For a C-language program, an array of strings called the environment shall be made available when a process begins. The array is pointed to by the external variable *environ*, which is defined as:
>
> ```
> extern char **environ;
> ```
>
> These strings have the form *name=value*; *names* shall not contain the character '='.

Comment: Ok thk, in short, what I have to do ?

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron, um...don't use arrays for things you want to pass via environment variables?  I don't really know what you're trying to achieve.  You asked why you can't do a specific thing; I explained.  The inability to pass arrays via environment variables has never stopped me.

Comment: thk, I now use string.

Comment: OP has a clear objective which can be solved with `BASH_ENV` environment script. So a command can be executed like `BASH_ENV=~/array.sh ~/command.sh`. So basically the bash evironment can be declared inside bash script and declarations within the script can therefore be called environment declarations.

Answer (score 1):

**Current Array Export Situation 10/2021**

Array export is not fully implemented yet. You can clone the source code with command `git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/bash.git ~/bash-src`. Look into the bash source `~/bash-src/config-top.h` for the commented line 154:

```
/* Define to 1 if you want to be able to export indexed arrays to processes
   using the foo=([0]=one [1]=two) and so on */
/* #define ARRAY_EXPORT 1 */
```

and furthermore the code section in `~/bash-src/variables.c` at line 429 which says

```
#if defined (ARRAY_VARS)
#  if ARRAY_EXPORT
      /* Array variables may not yet be exported. */
      if (*string == '(' && string[1] == '[' && string[strlen (string) - 1] == ')')
    {
      string_length = 1;
      temp_string = extract_array_assignment_list (string, &string_length);
      temp_var = assign_array_from_string (name, temp_string, 0);
      FREE (temp_string);
      VSETATTR (temp_var, (att_exported | att_imported));
      array_needs_making = 1;
    }
      else
#  endif /* ARRAY_EXPORT */
#endif
```

so basically some more work has to be put into this issue.

**Workaround**

Meanwhile you can export the `BASH_ENV` variable which can point to an environment script. I put mine into `/etc/bash.environment` and declare system-wide arrays there. Your `~/.bashrc` could contain something like `export BASH_ENV="~/.bash.environment"`, now every bash process executed by the current user will source this file.

As @they mentioned below an according `~/.bashrc` configuration to take effect on interactive AND noninteractive shells is needed:

```
[ -r "~/.bash.environment" ] \
&& source "~/.bash.environment" \
&& export BASH_ENV="~/.bash.environment"
```

And finally your environment:

```
# ~/.bash.environment
export HELLO="ee"
export HELLOO=(aaa bbbb ccc)
```

**Non-persistent Workaround**

A non-persistent solution for passing arrays quick and dirty could look like so, that you assign the named pipe created by process substitution `<()` to `BASH_ENV` environment variable:

```
BASH_ENV=<(declare -p HELLO HELLOO) your_script.sh
```

Best wishes

Comment: Note that `BASH_ENV` is only used for noninteractive shells, i.e. scripts.

Comment: True but OP asked about inheritance of associative arrays into scripts, which are mostly noninteractive. BASH_ENV is set in login or interactive shell and used by scripts. Now all scripts will source the file at startup time, even those which will never need those arrays. its tricky.